# PDOException when populating file field programaticalily?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm creating a drupal commerce product programatically and trying to populate it with a file using the following code:

```
$new_product = commerce_product_new($product_type);

$new_product->created = $new_product->changed = time();

$new_product->field_pdf[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = $extras['file'];

commerce_product_save($new_product);
```

This is the value of `$extras['file']`;

Keys: `fid`, `uri`, `filename`, `filemime`, `uid`, `status`, `timestamp`, filesize Values: `135`, `public://pdfs/test2_106.pdf`, `test2.pdf`, `application/pdf`, `0`, `1`, `1356742160`, `3908`

My problem is I get this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'field_pdf_display' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {field_data_field_pdf} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_pdf_fid, field_pdf_display, field_pdf_description) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => commerce_product [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 113 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 115 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => policy [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 128 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 448 of /var/www/clients/client1/web10/web/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
```

I have absolutely no idea what the problem might be. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's in `$extras['file']`?

Comment: Edited with array contents.

Comment: Try adding `$extras['file']['display'] = 1;` before you add it to the field

Comment: Between you and Berdir I got this solved. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file field item is not the same thing as a file object/array. You need to set the keys as defined in `file_field_schema`, which means fid, display and description.

Comment: For some reason creating a file array that only contained those fields left me with a duplicate uri '' error, but adding the display and description field to the file I already had worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$extras['file']['display'] = 1;
```

before you add it to the field as [@Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54356/pdoexception-when-populating-file-field-programaticalily#comment57257_54356) suggested in the comment.